# How can I get the current city name for an Android device without using GPS?

Tags: android, gps, locationmanager

I am currently able to get the city name in an Android application using GPS or network provider.

I tried with LocationManager, but if GPS is off the location manager and location is null. To improve the battery performance I don't want to turn on the GPS.

Is there any way without turning on the GPS able to get the city name in an Android application? Or if GPS is off why is location manager returning null? How can I solve this?

Comment: No. It's not possible.

Comment: Yes i tried so many times

Comment: @ Johan You want your Current City ?

Comment: @John You should first take a look [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Yes Rishi Paul. but without turn on the GPS

Answer (score 8):

Querying the following URL will give the current IP address and location in JSON:

http://ip-api.com/json

You can then parse that to extract the values you want.

Comment: Using android phone how i will get

Comment: @Johan If you want to use in your Project. then use this API with JSON parsing. And rest you have to use GPS.

Comment: @ Rishi Paul GET or POST . i need to call like web service call?